# ASP.net MVC Checkbox Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, checkboxfor

I am working on an ASP.net MVC project and I am using the `CheckBoxFor` helper method to provide the value for a `boolean` in my model like so:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ShouldSaveSearch, new { id="ShouldSaveSearch"})
```

If the checkbox gets **checked** by the user, it works completely fine and when the model is received by the controller. The ShouldSaveSearch property will be set to true.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search(int studentSearchId = -1)
{
    return View(new StudentSearchModel(studentSearchId));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(StudentSearchModel m)
{
    ViewBag.SearchResults = Hub.Web.Models.Student.StudentSearchModel.Search(m);
    Hub.Web.Models.Student.StudentSearchModel.Save(m);
    m.ShouldSaveSearch = false;
    m.ShouldShareSearch = false;
    m.SavedSearchName = "";
    m.SavedSearchDescription = "";

    return View(m);
}
```

I then set the `ShouldSaveSearch` property to `false` and then return the same view with the same model that was originally submitted.

However, when the view renders, the checkbox for this property remains checked.  Is there something that I am missing that is preventing the checkbox from unchecking itself?

Comment: It looks like you are resetting the form and then re-displaying the view.  A better practice (the post-redirect-get pattern) would be to `RedirectToAction("Search")`<--targeting the GET request for the view instead of the POST

Comment: You don't need the id = "ShouldSaveSearch" - that would be generated by mvc itself. Second, where is the [HttpPost] attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `ModelState` problem discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645479/mvc3-view-not-updating-after-post) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787895/asp-net-mvc-reset-the-value-of-textarea-after-form-submition)

In a few words the HtmlHelper displays `ModelState` value not `Model`. See question for more details.

Possible options:

- Implement the post-redirect-get pattern as suggested by Forty-Two
- Reset the checkbox value using the `ModelState` collection, something like `ModelState["ShouldSaveSearch"].Value = false`

Comment: This was indeed my problem, however, clearing the ModelState would remove other values from it that I do not want to be removed, and attempting the `ModelState["ShouldSaveSearch"].Value = false` solution returns an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult'".

Comment: I was able to remove the one value by `ModelState["ShouldSaveSearch"].Value = new ValueProviderResult("", "", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);`.

Comment: As a further update, I was able to simplify it by saying `m.ShouldSaveSearch = false;` and then `ModelState.Remove("ShouldSaveSearch");`

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to default the checkbox to unchecked. That is **Not** linked to the true/false value of lambda but the value of checked attribute

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ShouldSaveSearch, new { @checked="false"})
```

The other's points are equally important. Clear the ModelState!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that if you return the same view to which you posted with the model data, MVC will think that you are returning because of an error. This is a normal behavior. If you want to redisplay the view then you should implement PRG pattern (Post-Redirect-Get). You issue will be always there regardless of whether `ModelState.IsValid` is true or false. You should redirect to the HttpGet version of your view, passing the parameter, and loading the data. If you want to avoid loading, store the data in `TempData` or some other Session implementation.

UPDATE: You are calling the version of an action that receives model object. Once you persist data call

```
return RedirectToAction("Search", new {studentSearchId = your_value});
```