# The field in the view doesn't get populated after passing the viewmodel to view on post action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Hi this is more of an MVC question. I am implementing a save functionality in my MVC application. I have written a HTTPPOST method to save the records. When I am trying to pass the viewmodel to the view , I am amending one of the properties called requestID. This requestid is retrieved after i save a request. When my view loads I dont see the requestid field containing the data. I have bound the control correctly. Do you loose the viewmodel information during the post operation. What I am looking at is I need to refresh my view with the latest request that I have saved.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Request_Insert(NewRequestViewModel newRequestViewModel)
{

    newRequestViewModel.CompanyCode = "8100";
    newRequestViewModel.RequestStatusCode = "New";
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return null;
    }
    int requestId = requestRepository.CreateRequest(Mapper.Map<Request>(newRequestViewModel));

    newRequestViewModel.RequestID = requestId;


    return View("NewRequestView", Mapper.Map<NewRequestViewModel>(newRequestViewModel));
}
```

**Requestid field**

```
@model CC.GRP.MCRequest.ViewModels.NewRequestViewModel
     <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:100%", @readonly = "readonly" } })

                            </div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Can't tell from your 'Requestid Field' code, but I assume that the ViewModel is wrapped inside a Form that is sending the data to the controller via a post?

Comment: And have you checked that the object returned from Mapper.Map contains the new Id ?

Comment: I get the value of the requestid after executing CreateRequest method. I am doing a manual assignment.. When I check the newReqeustViewModel object value while debugging it contains the requestid

Comment: try ModelState.Clear(), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787895/reset-the-value-of-textarea-after-form-submission

Comment: where do I put it

Comment: It works . Thank you